# golang: optimal sorting and joining strings

Tags: string, memory-management, go, slice

[This](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/http2/transport.go#L649) short method in go's source code has a comment which implies that it's not allocating memory in an optimal way.

> ... could do better allocation-wise here ...

[This](https://golang.org/src/strings/strings.go?s=8854:8894#L334) is the source code for the `Join` method.

What exactly is inefficiently allocated here? I don't see a way around allocating the source string slice and the destination byte slice. The source being the slice of keys. The destination being the slice of bytes.

Comment: Not referring to the link specifically, but `strings.Join()` does a lot of allocation and copying for concatenation. For large strings, this can be expensive compared to other approaches like using Buffer / `io.Writer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code referenced by the comment](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/8fd7f25955530b92e73e9e1932a41b522b22ccd9/http2/transport.go#L661-L663) is memory efficient as written. Any allocations are in `strings.Join` which is written to minimize memory allocations.

I suspect that the comment was accidentally copied and pasted from this [code in the net/http package](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e776975ae61e8db6ff5db33b039513c9d8524794/src/net/http/transfer.go#L289-L294):

```
        // TODO: could do better allocation-wise here, but trailers are rare,
        // so being lazy for now.
        if _, err := io.WriteString(w, "Trailer: "+strings.Join(keys, ",")+"\r\n"); err != nil {
            return err
        }
```

This snippet has the following possible allocations:

- [`[]byte` created in strings.Join for constructing the result](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e776975ae61e8db6ff5db33b039513c9d8524794/src/strings/strings.go#L360)
- [`string` conversion result returned by strings.Join](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e776975ae61e8db6ff5db33b039513c9d8524794/src/strings/strings.go#L366)
- string result for expression `"Trailer: "+strings.Join(keys, ",")+"\r\n"`
- [The `[]byte` conversion result used in io.WriteString](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e776975ae61e8db6ff5db33b039513c9d8524794/src/io/io.go#L291)

A more memory efficient approach is to allocate a single `[]byte` for the data to be written.

```
n := len("Trailer: ") + len("\r\n")
for _, s := range keys {
    n += len(s) + 1
}
p := make([]byte, 0, n-1) // subtract 1 for len(keys) - 1 commas
p = append(p, "Trailer: "...)
for i, s := range keys {
    if i > 0 {
        p = append(p, ',')
    }
    p = append(p, s...)
}
p = append(p, "\r\n"...)
w.Write(p)
```